# C - Array of structs within struct returning unexpected results in dfa program

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I am trying to make a program that creates a dfa based on user input. Each node and transition must be a struct and the dfa is also a struct. The dfa struct contains an array of node structs and a linked list of transition structs. 
Here is what I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_STATES 25
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0
#define MAXCHAR 256

/* struct for a state of the DFA */
typedef struct state {
    char *id;
    int isInitial;
    int isFinal;
} STATE_T;

/* struct for a transition of the DFA*/
typedef struct transition {
    STATE_T *startState;
    char condition;
    STATE_T *endState;
    struct transistion *next;
} TRANSITION_T;

/* struct for the DFA */
typedef struct automaton {
    STATE_T state[MAX_STATES];
    TRANSITION_T *transition;
} AUTOMATON_T;

/* main function reads initial user inputs to build dfa */
int main() {
    AUTOMATON_T dfa;
    STATE_T stateA;
    TRANSITION_T *trans;
```

The first line of the text file is comma sperated nodes/states, for example: "a,b,c". But when I get to assigning each node as a state id into the dfa struct, the final state is assigned to the id for every single state. The for statement in the following code prints 0c 1c 2c where I would expect 0a 1b 2c.

```
    FILE *fp = fopen(fileName, "r");

    while (fgets(useIn, MAXCHAR, fp)) {
        if (lineNum == 0) {
            i = 0;
            char *token = strtok(useIn, ",");
            while (token != NULL) {
                strcpy(stateId, token);
                stateA.id = stateId;
                dfa.state[i] = stateA;
                i++;
                token = strtok(NULL, ",");
            }
            stateAmt = i;
            for (i = 0; i < stateAmt; i++) {
                printf("%d", i);
                printf("%s", dfa.state[i].id);
            }
        }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Why would this be? Am I handling the array of states incorrectly?

Comment: Hints: where does the state's `id` point after you've done `stateA.id = stateId;`? Is there a difference between the states?

Comment: What is lineNum? where does it get its value? [BTW: fgets() keeps the final '\n' in the buffer, you should deal with that, too] And stateId is never defined. Is it a buffer? a pointer ?

Comment: I suggest that you read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for tips on debugging your code.

Comment: @joop I removed some code to keep the post concise which may have made it more difficult for me to get an answer. lineNum is initialized at 0 and "lineNum++;" is at the end of the fgets while loop. stateId is initialized just inside main as "char stateId[MAXCHAR]; "

Comment: @molbdnilo There should be a difference between the states. I am still contemplating your question, so I need to think for a sec before fully answering, I'm very slow with C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is these two lines:

```
strcpy(stateId, token);
stateA.id = stateId;
```

In the `state` structure, the `id` member is a pointer to a mutable string. The memory for storing that string was only allocated once, and its address has been stored in each state struct.

In order for each state to have its own ID, you need to allocate a new ID buffer for each state. You could do this dynamically using `malloc` at run-time, or you could simply include the storage for this buffer as part of the `state` structure like this:

```
typedef struct state {
    char id[MAX_ID_LENGTH+1];
    int isInitial;
    int isFinal;
} STATE_T;
```

Comment: This makes complete sense! But now my code turned up another issue within the same section. I believe you gave me some progress so I'm going to try to use some intuition to finish before I state that everything worked.